# How can one perform high precision convolution in Python?

Tags: python, scientific-computing, convolution

I am doing convolution operations involving some very small numbers, and am encountering a lot of underflow on the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) package coming in standard library. If it doesn't work for you, there are other alternatives like [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) or [bigfloat](http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/).